# Secure input field to allow only keyboard

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it possible to check how the input [type = "text"] field is filled?

More precisely, is it possible to completely protect against filling in the field other than from the keyboard, so that it cannot be filled in from the JS or console

Ex code that should not pass this security:

```
$('input')[0].focus();

theKey = 1;
keyCode = 'Digit1';
 
document.activeElement.value = theKey;

document.getElementById('PinnedBetslip').dispatchEvent(new Event('input', {
   bubbles: true,
   cancelable: true,
}));
document.activeElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', {
   bubbles: true,
   cancelable: true,
}));

document.activeElement.dispatchEvent((new window.KeyboardEvent('keydown', {
   bubbles: true,
   key: theKey,
   keyCode: keyCode,
   charCode: 0,
})));

document.activeElement.dispatchEvent((new window.KeyboardEvent('keyup ', {
   bubbles: true,
   key: theKey,
   keyCode: keyCode,
   charCode: 0,
})));
```

EDIT---------------------------
This is example page with such input: https://pl.unibet-34.com/betting/sports/home

When You click any bet button, it will show betting slip with input, there is no way to  set its value from the JS/Console, I've used timeout, all possible events without success.

[image]

Comment: Listen on click, focus, keyup, keydown events and interval between typed letters must differ and have proper interval

Answer (score 0):

Well from what I know there is no reliable ways to do that. Because in the end user actions dispatch the same kind of events as JS code.

If you want to protect your form from being submitted by a robot use captcha.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I've edited my question with example site where I found such input

Answer (score 0):

You can use **event.isTrusted** that is defined in latest specification. It is not supported by all browsers but it can be helpful.

You can read more about it here

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted